# How to create correlation functions without using any packages?

Tags: python

Over the week, I was assigned to create a function in **Jupyter Notebook py that satisfies the Spearman Correlation formula without the use of any packages etc Numpy Pandas**. Below are the rules of the game, followed by solution.

I am seeking any input on how this could be done more efficiently. Thank you in advance!

'''The Spearman rank correlation is used to evaluate if the relationship between two variables, X and Y is monotonic. The rank correlation measures how closely related the ordering of one variable to the other variable, with no regard to the actual values of the variables.
To calculate the Spearman rank correlation for X and Y, ρS(X, Y):

• the values of X and Y are ranked in an ascending order respectively. The **smallest value will be given a rank of 1, the next smaller value will be given a rank of 2, etc**. If there are multiple entries with the same value, then each entry is ranked equal to the average position.

• the rank difference for the i-th pair of xi and yi is then calculated and,
(,)=1−6Σ2=1(2−1)
where N is the total pairs of data points and di is the rank difference for the i-th pair of data.

**Create a function calculate_spearman_rank_correlation(X, Y) that returns you the value of the rank correlation, given two sets of data X and Y.'''**

My solution:

```
def calculate_spearman_rank_correlation(X,Y):
'''
#The Spearman rank correlation is used to evaluate if the relationship between two variables, 
X and Y is monotonic. The rank correlation measures how closely related the ordering of one
variable to the other variable, with no regard to the actual values of the variables. 
'''
if len(X) != len(Y): #Making sure length is the same
    return("Please check your dataset again for input errors.") 
else:
    # for X
    xranks = [sorted(X).index(x) + 1 for x in X]
    dupesx = [x for n, x in enumerate(xranks) if x in xranks[:n]]
    if len(dupesx) == 0: 
        print(xranks)
    else:
        
        dupenumberx = dupesx[0]
        count_ax = xranks.count(dupesx[0])
    
        sumx = 0
        tx = 0
        while tx < count_ax:
            sumx = sumx + dupenumberx + 1*tx
            tx=tx+1
            sumx2 = sumx/count_ax
            for i in range(len(xranks)):
                if xranks[i] == dupenumberx:
                    xranks[i] = sumx2
                    
    # for Y
    yranks = [sorted(Y).index(y) + 1 for y in Y]
    dupesy = [y for n, y in enumerate(yranks) if y in yranks[:n]]
    if len(dupesy) == 0: 
        print(yranks)
    else:
        
        dupenumbery = dupesy[0]
        count_ay = yranks.count(dupesy[0])
    
        sumy = 0
        ty = 0
        while ty < count_ay:
            sumy = sumy + dupenumbery + 1*ty
            ty=ty+1
            sumy2 = sumy/count_ay
            for i in range(len(yranks)):
                if yranks[i] == dupenumbery:
                    yranks[i] = sumy2
    

    # calculate rank difference for the i-th pair of data
    sub_list = []
    zip_object = zip(xranks, yranks)
    for xranks_i, yranks_i in zip_object:
        sub_list.append(xranks_i - yranks_i)
        
    # inplementing the formula for SRC
    sub_list2 = [i **2 for i in sub_list]
    di = sum(sub_list2)
    N = len(X)
    SRC = (1 - (6 * (di))/(N*((N**2)-1)))
    SRC_1dp = round(SRC, 3)
return "The Spearman rank correlation is", SRC_1dp
```

The test sets:

```
# test case a
Xa = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
Ya = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
calculate_spearman_rank_correlation(Xa,Ya)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
('The Spearman rank correlation is', 1.0)
```

test:

```
# test case b
Xb= [10, 20, 20, 50, 40]
Yb= [2, 10, 6, 4, 8]
calculate_spearman_rank_correlation(Xb,Yb)
```

output:

```
[1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
('The Spearman rank correlation is', -0.45)
```

test:

```
# test case d
Xd= [50, 50, 50, 30, 30, 30]
Yd= [2, 10, 8, 6, 10, 10]
calculate_spearman_rank_correlation(Xd,Yd)
```

output:

```
 ('The Spearman rank correlation is', 0.883)
```

Comment: Perhaps this might belong better on code review stack exchange?

Comment: didnt knew that existed, thanks!